# How to find indices of identical sub-sequences in two strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dna-sequence

Here each instance of the class `DNA` corresponds to a string such as `'GCCCAC'`. Arrays of substrings containing *k-mers* can be constructed from these strings. For this string there are 1-mers, 2-mers, 3-mers, 4-mers, 5-mers and one 6-mer:

- 6 1-mers: `["G", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C"]`
- 5 2-mers: `["GC", "CC", "CC", "CA", "AC"]`
- 4 3-mers: `["GCC", "CCC", "CCA", "CAC"]`
- 3 4-mers: `["GCCC", "CCCA", "CCAC"]`
- 2 5-mers: `["GCCCA", "CCCAC"]`
- 1 6-mers: `["GCCCAC"]`

The pattern should be evident. See the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer) for details.

The problem is to write the method shared_kmers(k, dna2) of the DNA class which returns an array of all pairs [i, j] where this DNA object (that receives the message) shares with dna2 a common k-mer at position i in this dna and at position j in dna2.

```
dna1 = DNA.new('GCCCAC')
dna2 = DNA.new('CCACGC')

dna1.shared_kmers(2, dna2)
#=> [[0, 4], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 2]]

dna2.shared_kmers(2, dna1)
#=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 0]]

dna1.shared_kmers(3, dna2)
#=> [[2, 0], [3, 1]]

dna1.shared_kmers(4, dna2)
#=> [[2, 0]]

dna1.shared_kmers(5, dna2)
#=> []
```

Comment: What does the first argument to `shared_kmers` mean? The number you're passing from 2-5.

Comment: "The problem is to write the method shared_kmers(k, dna2)..." which sounds very much like homework. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" will help you understand the SO opinion of homework problems. Remember that SO is an extremely visible site, visited by teachers and students alike, so your question could very well be visible to someone who expects you to answer it on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class DNA
  attr_accessor :sequencing

  def initialize(sequencing)
    @sequencing = sequencing
  end

  def kmers(k)
    @sequencing.each_char.each_cons(k).map(&:join)
  end

  def shared_kmers(k, dna)
    kmers(k).each_with_object([]).with_index do |(kmer, result), index|
      dna.kmers(k).each_with_index do |other_kmer, other_kmer_index|
        result << [index, other_kmer_index] if kmer.eql?(other_kmer)
      end
    end
  end
end

dna1 = DNA.new('GCCCAC')
dna2 = DNA.new('CCACGC')

dna1.kmers(2)
#=> ["GC", "CC", "CC", "CA", "AC"]

dna2.kmers(2)
#=> ["CC", "CA", "AC", "CG", "GC"]

dna1.shared_kmers(2, dna2)
#=> [[0, 4], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 2]]

dna2.shared_kmers(2, dna1)
#=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 0]]

dna1.shared_kmers(3, dna2)
#=> [[2, 0], [3, 1]]

dna1.shared_kmers(4, dna2)
#=> [[2, 0]]

dna1.shared_kmers(5, dna2)
#=> []
```

Comment: Good answer. I tiny suggestion, so tiny that it may not even deserve mention: by replacing `chars` with `each_char` in `@sequencing.chars.each_cons(k)` you can avoid the creation of a temporary array. The rule: use `each_char` when chained to an `Enumerator` or `Enumerable` method; use `chars` when it is not chained or is chained to an `Array` method.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for suggestion @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 2):

I will address the crux of your problem only, without reference to a class `DNA`. It should be easy to reorganize what follows quite easily.

**Code**

```
def match_kmers(s1, s2, k)
  h1 = dna_to_index(s1, k)
  h2 = dna_to_index(s2, k)
  h1.flat_map { |k,_| h1[k].product(h2[k] || []) }
end
```

```
def dna_to_index(dna, k)
  dna.each_char.
      with_index.
      each_cons(k).
      with_object({}) {|arr,h| (h[arr.map(&:first).join] ||= []) << arr.first.last}
end
```

**Examples**

```
dna1 = 'GCCCAC'
dna2 = 'CCACGC'
```

```
match_kmers(dna1, dna2, 2)
  #=> [[0, 4], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 2]] 
match_kmers(dna2, dna1, 2)
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 0]]
```

```
match_kmers(dna1, dna2, 3)
  #=> [[2, 0], [3, 1]] 
match_kmers(dna2, dna1, 3)
  #=> [[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

```
match_kmers(dna1, dna2, 4)
  #=> [[2, 0]] 
match_kmers(dna2, dna1, 4)
  #=> [[0, 2]]
```

```
match_kmers(dna1, dna2, 5)
  #=> [] 
match_kmers(dna2, dna1, 5)
  #=> []
```

```
match_kmers(dna1, dna2, 6)
  #=> [] 
match_kmers(dna2, dna1, 6)
  #=> []
```

**Explanation**

Consider `dna1 = 'GCCCAC'`. This contains 5 2-mers (`k = 2`):

```
dna1.each_char.each_cons(2).to_a.map(&:join)
  #=> ["GC", "CC", "CC", "CA", "AC"]
```

Similarly, for `dna2 = 'CCACGC'`:

```
dna2.each_char.each_cons(2).to_a.map(&:join)
  #=> ["CC", "CA", "AC", "CG", "GC"]
```

These are the keys of the hashes produced by `dna_to_index` for `dna1` and `dna2`, respectively. The hash values are arrays of indices of where the corresponding key begins in the DNA string. Let's compute those hashes for `k = 2`:

```
h1 = dna_to_index(dna1, 2)
  #=> {"GC"=>[0], "CC"=>[1, 2], "CA"=>[3], "AC"=>[4]} 
h2 = dna_to_index(dna2, 2)
  #=> {"CC"=>[0], "CA"=>[1], "AC"=>[2], "CG"=>[3], "GC"=>[4]}
```

`h1` shows that:

- `"GC"` begins at index 0 of `dna1`
- `"CC"` begins at indices 1 and 2 of `dna1`
- `"CA"` begins at index 3 of `dna1`
- `"CC"` begins at index 4 of `dna1`

`h2` has a similar interpretation. See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-product).

The method `match_kmers` is then used to construct the desired array of pairs of indices `[i, j]` such that `h1[i] = h2[j]`.

Now let's look at the hashes produced for 3-mers (`k = 3`):

```
h1 = dna_to_index(dna1, 3)
  #=> {"GCC"=>[0], "CCC"=>[1], "CCA"=>[2], "CAC"=>[3]} 
h2 = dna_to_index(dna2, 3)
  #=> {"CCA"=>[0], "CAC"=>[1], "ACG"=>[2], "CGC"=>[3]}
```

We see that the first 3-mer in `dna1` is `"GCC"`, beginning at index 0. This 3-mer does not appear in `dna2`, however, so there are no elements `[0, X]` in the array returned (`X` being just a placeholder). Nor is `"CCC"` a key in the second hash. `"CCA"` and `"CAC"` are present in the second hash, however, so the array returned is:

```
h1["CCA"].product(h2["CCA"]) + h1["CAC"].product(h2["CAC"]) 
  #=> [[2, 0]] + [[3, 1]]
  #=> [[2, 0], [3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing a method to enumerate subsequences of a given length (i.e. the k-mers):

```
class DNA
  def initialize(sequence)
    @sequence = sequence
  end

  def each_kmer(length)
    return enum_for(:each_kmer, length) unless block_given?

    0.upto(@sequence.length - length) { |i| yield @sequence[i, length] }
  end
end

DNA.new('GCCCAC').each_kmer(2).to_a
#=> ["GC", "CC", "CC", "CA", "AC"]
```

On top of this you can easily collect the indices of identical k-mers using a nested loop:

```
class DNA
  # ...

  def shared_kmers(length, other)
    indices = []
    each_kmer(length).with_index do |k, i|
      other.each_kmer(length).with_index do |l, j|
        indices << [i, j] if k == l
      end
    end
    indices
  end
end

dna1 = DNA.new('GCCCAC')
dna2 = DNA.new('CCACGC')

dna1.shared_kmers(2, dna2)
#=> [[0, 4], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 2]]
```

Unfortunately, the above code traverses `other.each_kmer` for each k-mer in the receiver. We can optimize this by building a hash containing all indices for each k-mer in `other` up-front:

```
class DNA
  # ...

  def shared_kmers(length, other)
    hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
    other.each_kmer(length).with_index { |k, i| hash[k] << i }

    indices = []
    each_kmer(length).with_index do |k, i|
      hash[k].each { |j| indices << [i, j] }
    end
    indices
  end
end
```